# Using stripe to save the user's card info to be charged for future

Tags: reactjs, typescript, stripe-payments

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux"
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js"
import { StripeError } from "@stripe/stripe-js"
import { AppState } from "../store"
import { Button, Card } from "./Dashboard"
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebase/compat/firestore"

interface CardInfo {
  card: string
  amount: number
}

interface User {
  uid: string
  email: string
}

const UserCardProcessor: React.FC<{
  setError: (error: string) => void
  navigate: (path: string) => void
  currentUser: User
}> = ({ setError, navigate, currentUser }) => {
  const stripe = useStripe()
  const elements = useElements()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const pushkaSize = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.pushkaSize)
  const firestore = firebase.firestore()
  const userId = currentUser?.uid
  const [savedCard, setSavedCard] = useState<CardInfo | null>(null)

  const handlePushkaSizeChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const value = Number(event.target.value)
    dispatch({ type: "SET_PUSHKA_SIZE", payload: value })
  }

  const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setError("")

    try {
      if (!stripe || !elements) {
        // Stripe.js has not yet loaded
        return
      }

      const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement)

      // Tokenize the card information
      const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
        type: "card",
        card: cardElement!,
      })

      if (error) {
        // Handle card processing error
        const stripeError = error as StripeError
        setError(stripeError?.message || "Failed to process card information")
      } else {
        // Payment method created successfully, handle the paymentMethod object (e.g., send to server for processing)
        console.log(paymentMethod)

        if (userId) {
          // Update the user document in the Firestore collection to store card information
          await firestore
            .collection("users")
            .doc(userId)
            .set({
              cardInfo: {
                card: paymentMethod.card,
                amount: pushkaSize,
              },
            })
        }

        // Create a new document in the Firestore collection
        const paymentDocRef = await firestore.collection("customers").doc(userId).collection("checkout_sessions").add({
          client: "mobile",
          mode: "payment",
          amount: pushkaSize,
          currency: "usd",
        })

        // Listen for changes in the document to integrate with the mobile payment sheet
        paymentDocRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          const { mode } = snapshot.data() || {}
          console.log("snapshot.data()", snapshot.data())
          console.log("paymentMethod", paymentMethod)
          if (mode) {
            // navigate(`/main`) // Pass pushkaSize as a route parameter
            dispatch({ type: "SET_PAYMENT_METHOD", payload: paymentMethod })
          } else {
            setError("Incomplete mobile payment sheet response")
          }
        })
      }
    } catch (error: unknown) {
      const errorMessage = (error as Error)?.message || "Failed to process card information"
      setError(errorMessage)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCardInfo = async () => {
      try {
        if (userId) {
          const userDoc = await firestore.collection("users").doc(userId).get()
          const userData = userDoc.data()
          if (userData && userData.cardInfo) {
            setSavedCard(userData.cardInfo)
            console.log("userData", userData)
          } else {
            setSavedCard(null)
            console.log("setSavedcarnull")
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to fetch card info:", error)
      }
    }

    fetchCardInfo()
  }, [firestore, userId])

  return (
    <Card>
      <h2>Card Information</h2>
      {savedCard ? (
        <p>
          Card: {savedCard.card}, Pushka Size: {savedCard.amount}
        </p>
      ) : (
        <p>No saved card information found.</p>
      )}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <CardElement id="cardNumber" options={{ style: { base: { fontSize: "16px" } } }} />

        <label htmlFor="cardHolder">Card Holder:</label>

        <label htmlFor="pushkaSize">Pushka Size:</label>
        <input type="number" id="pushkaSize" name="pushkaSize" value={pushkaSize} onChange={handlePushkaSizeChange} />
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default UserCardProcessor
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my code. I am using the pushka size charge the amount at later date. But No saved card information found is the only value being shown. How do I save the card info of customer?

this is my index.ts for my firebase cloud functions

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions"
import * as admin from "firebase-admin"
import Stripe from "stripe"

admin.initializeApp()
const stripe = new Stripe(functions.config().stripe.secret_key, {
  apiVersion: "2022-11-15",
})
export const chargeUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // Verify user authentication
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unauthenticated", "User is not authenticated.")
  }

  try {
    // Retrieve user's card information from Firestore
    const userId = context.auth.uid
    const userDoc = await admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).get()
    const cardInfo = userDoc.data()?.cardInfo
    console.log("cardInfo", cardInfo)
    // Create a Stripe Customer
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
      email: context.auth.token.email,
      payment_method: data.paymentMethod.id,
    })

    // Retrieve the Customer ID from the Stripe Customer object
    const customerId = customer.id

    // Create a Stripe PaymentIntent
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: Math.round(data.amount * 100),
      currency: "usd",
      customer: customerId, // Use the retrieved Customer ID here
      payment_method: data.paymentMethod.id, // Pass the paymentMethod ID received from the client
      off_session: true, // Set to true if the payment is not immediately triggered by user action
      confirm: true, // Confirm the PaymentIntent immediately
      // payment_method_types: ["card"], // Specify the supported payment method type(s) here
      // automatic_payment_methods: {
      //   enabled: true,
      // },
      return_url: "https://your-pushka-auth-development.web.app/main", // Replace with your desired return URL
    })
    console.log("index data.paymentMethod.id", data.paymentMethod.id)
    console.log("index data.paymentMethod", data.paymentMethod)

    // Update user's pushka size in Firestore
    const pushkaSize = data.amount
    await admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).update({
      cardInfo: cardInfo,
      customerId: customerId,
      pushkaSize: pushkaSize,
    })

    // Add customer data to Firestore customers collection
    const customerData = {
      userId: userId,
      cardInfo: cardInfo,
      pushkaSize: pushkaSize,
      paymentIntentId: paymentIntent,
      customerId: customerId, // Store the Customer ID in Firestore as well
    }
    await admin.firestore().collection("customers").add(customerData)

    return { success: true }
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", error.message)
    } else {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", "internal error occurred")
    }
  }
})
```

I tried to save the card to the fire store docs but it is not being saved.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what exactly is failing? Are you receiving an error and, if so, at what point?